# How to Disable or do minimal Logging for apache spark client Driver program?

Tags: apache-spark

How to Disable or do minimal Logging for apache spark client Driver program? By Driver program I mean the program where I initialize spark context. It produces lot of INFO messages but I would like to know only when there is error or a Exception such as Nullpointer exception and so on.
I am also using spark standalone mode

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark uses log4j. In conf/log4j.properties, modify the following line(s) with your desired logging level:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console    
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN
```

You can find more information here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging

Comment: They both are set to WARN already and the driver program still produces INFO messages.

Comment: If you're running with Yarn, perhaps you could try explicitly passing the log4j.properties file with your submit using the "--files path/to/log4j.properties" option.

Comment: I am using standalone mode and I dont submit job using command line. I just invoke public static void main() of my driver program

Answer (score 0):

```
javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR");
```